# AngularJS UI-Bootstrap modal passing parameters to modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying since couple of days to open a modal and passing it some parameters based on the link the user will click.

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8 and UI-Bootstrap 2.1.3 with Bootstrap CSS 3.3.7. I'm beginning with AngularJS and UI-Bootstrap and getting familiar with it, and this should be straightforward but for some reasons it's not. I have looked on many different solutions on Stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.

I'm sure my error comes from the controller definition as I'm getting an "Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider" error

My HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlForm" class="container-fluid">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            {{modalContent}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$close()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg">
                <input name="lala" type="radio" ng-model="bSType" value="type1" ng-Model="mdlType1" ng-checked="!mdlType2">&nbsp;Type 1 - 
                <a href="#" role="button" ng-click="open('type1')">What is it?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="bSType" value="type1" ng-Model="mdlType2" ng-checked="!mdlType2">&nbsp; Type 2 - <a href="#" role="button" ng-click="open('type2')">What is it?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form> 
</div>
```

I'm using javascript by calling my code through the following call at the end before the  :

```
<script src="../scripts/parent/parent.js"></script>
```

The parent.js contains the code below :

```
var app = angular.module('TCB', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);

  //[Edit] I have updated the method's signature below as recommended
  angular.module('TCB').controller('NavBarCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapsed = true;
});

//[Edit] Same for method below
angular.module('TCB').controller('ctrlForm', ["$scope", function ($scope) {

  $scope.Languages = {

    language01: "Fran" + String.fromCharCode(231) + "ais",
    language02: "Anglais"
  }

  $scope.Children = {
    child01: 01,
    child02: 02,
    child03: 03,
    child04: 04
  }

  $scope.numberChildren = $scope.Children.child01;

});

//[Edit] And same for this one
angular.module('TCB').controller('ctrlForm', ["$scope", "$modal", "$log", function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  var key = 1000;
  items = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];

  $scope.open = function (type) {

    alert("type: " + type);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            item: function () {
                return type;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, item) {

  alert("I'm on modal " + item)


  $scope.cancel = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

[Edit]
I have referenced in the head all the needed script files and css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ui-bootstrap-csp.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

The detailed error message is :

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20ctrlForm
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:6:412
at http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:43:174
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:40:432)
at http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:43:236
at d (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:40:432)
at e (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:41:158)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:41:243)
at S.instance (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:89:436)
at p (http://localhost:4400/scripts/angular.min.js:65:128)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13920(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10467$apply @ angular.js:17787(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1761invoke @ angular.js:4718c @ angular.js:1759Bc @ angular.js:1779fe @ angular.js:1664(anonymous function) @ angular.js:31763b @ angular.js:3207Sf @ angular.js:3497d @ angular.js:3485
```

Comment: have you referenced boostrap?

Comment: you need to post the full error message. "unknown provider" error can be caused by as simple as a typo.

Comment: @Sajeentharan: Yes, I did, let me edit the post

Comment: @ROTOGG: I have edited the post with the error message

Comment: try chaning your $modal to $uibModal

Answer (score 0):

If you follow your link, it tells you that the error results from the `$injector` not being able to resolve your dependencies. This is a common issue with angular when the javascript gets `minified/uglified/whatever` you're doing to it for production.

The issue is when you have e.g. a controller;

```
angular.module("TCB").controller('ctrlForm', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  // your code
})
```

The minification changes `$scope, $modal and $log` into random variables that doesn't tell angular what to inject. The solution is to declare your dependencies like this:

```
angular.module("TCB")
  .controller("ctrlForm", ["$scope", "$modal", "$log", function($scope,  $modal, $log) {
  // your code
}])
```

That should fix your problem.

Just to re-iterate, everything I've said is at the link the error message provides to you.

Comment: I have changed all the declarations as you suggested and pointed from the error description, but I'm still getting an $injector :unpr error http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20ctrlForm. Could this come from the fact that I do have twice the declaration "angular.module('TCB').controller('ctrlForm',(...)" even if the rest of the parameters aren't the same?

Comment: Yes, if you want multiple declaration ,the parameters should be the same

Comment: @john_v have you tested it?

Comment: Yes I did, let me update the code for better visibility

Comment: Apologies for late answer, I have been busy on another topic. I didn't pick again my angularjs project to confirm that, I will check out again when my current projects are over and will reply there with an appropriate status. I will definitively keep this answer on my notes to check it out asap